# MVC5 OWIN Authentication persistence works locally, but times out quickly when published

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I'm having an issue with login persistency using MVC5 OWIN authentication on my website.

I was using the code generated with the MVC5 template. When running locally on VS, it would keep my user logged for a long time, however, when I published, on the server it logs off after about 5 minutes.

I've tried already changing the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```

to

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```

but it didn't work.

Tried setting the ExpireTimeSpan in Startup.Auth.cs, but it didn't work as well.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
   AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
   LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
   ExpireTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(20, 0, 0)
});
```

Anyone has any idea what could I be doing wrong?

BTW, I'm not using ExternalLogins.

Comment: Try setting `SlidingExpiration = true` underneath `ExpireTimeSpan`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem and followed the same steps you did with no effect, even doing the suggestion of changing `SlidingExpiration = true`. I finally figured out to get this to work, I needed to add a `<machineKey/>` in my Web.config. And viola, it worked! Now my ticket stays authenticated in Production.

Comment: I came across this problem and found lots of code related fixes that did not work for me, but this one worked great. thanks